# Javascript selecting specific element from repetitive element class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an index page which displays a list of published posts, which contents pulled from the database. Posts are styled using class attribute.

Using javascript / jQuery, I want to modify the appearance of the block in which each post is being displayed. I can do that without any difficulties when the triggering action is one that directly corresponds to a specific post, for example a click action (then I can use 'this' selector to target that specific post's class). 
But how do I go about doing something similar, but when the action isn't related to a specific post? Like resizing the screen.

```
if($(window).width() <= 650) {
   $('.postBtn').appendTo('.smallScreenFooter');
}
```

This code results in having multiple `.postBtn`'s appended to each `.smallScreenFooter` in every post on the page (the number of buttons per single post is equal to the number of posts displayed on a page).

Comment: I read what your wrote but still do not fully understand what the intended behavior is to be? Care to extrapolate? Editing how something appears and adding buttons is different things

Comment: Please quote the HTML structure.

Comment: is the intent that, for each block, you want to append THAT BLOCK's post button to THAT BLOCK's small screen footer? If so, you'll need to loop.

Comment: Have you tried to use the "resize" event?? Like `$(window).on("resize", function(){ ... });` Your question is *unclear*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how do I go about doing something similar, but when the action isn't related to a specific post?

By using [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
if($(window).width() <= 650) {
   $('.post'/*or whatever the container's class is*/).each(function() {
       var post = $(this);
       post.find('.smallScreenFooter').append(post.find('.postBtn'));
   });
}
```

---

**That said**, this specific use case would probably be handled better with CSS media queries and two buttons per post, where the CSS hides one or the other depending on screen size.

Comment: I was considering that mentioned CSS solution, but I thought that duplicating that element might be excessful and doing it with js would be more elegant. Maybe I was wrong. Anyways, thanks for your answer - that's what I was looking for.